# How can I remove the space?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a program which transposes a matrix. My question is how to remove the space after every last number in row.

I know that the space is there because of the `end = " "`. The end makes a space after every number but how can I remove it from the last number in rows?  How can I replace the end?

```
p = input ()
M = str(p).split(" ")
A = int(M[0])
R = int(M[1])
X=[]
for i in range(A):
   l=list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
   X.append(l)
for i in range(R):
   for j in range(A):
      print(X[j][i], end = " ")
   print ()
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? That will let us see better what you're doing and where these extra spaces are coming from.

That said, there is a `.strip()` method which will remove all trailing spaces from a string, e.g. `'abc '.strip()` returns `'abc'`

Comment: I sent the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you only want spaces in between each number. The best way to do this is the `join` method, which operates on a delimiter, takes a list of strings, and creates a new string where the delimiter separates each string in the list.

For example,

```py
>>> " ".join(["1", "2", "3"])
'1 2 3'
```

You can use this in your code. Here is the final version:

```
p = input()
M = str(p).split(" ")
A = int(M[0])
R = int(M[1])
X = []
for i in range(A):
    l = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))
    X.append(l)
for i in range(R):
    row = [str(X[j][i]) for j in range(A)]
    print(" ".join(row))
```